# Let A = {1,{1},{2},{1,2}} and complete with ⊆ or ∈:

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone check over my answers? I'm having trouble getting intuition for things like this so any tips you guys may have is helpful too. Also is {1,2} the same thing as saying {1}∪{2}?

Let A = {1,{1},{2},{1,2}}

a) Fill in the blank with ⊆ or ∈:

1) Ø __ A My Answer: ∈

2) {1}∪{2} __ A  My Answer: ⊆

3) {1,2} __ A  My Answer: ∈

4){{2}} __ P(A)  My Answer: ⊆

5) A __ P(A)  My Answer: ∈

6) {{1},{2}} __ P(A)  My Answer: ⊆

b) How many elements are in P(A) ∪ A?

For this question i did $2^4 +4 = 20$ as there are 4 elements in A. Am I correct?

Comment: You forgot the [descriptive-set-theory] tag too.

Comment: @Mac I Retagged your question. Asaf was being sarcastic. The answers to a) 1, 2, 4 and 6 are wrong. The answer to b) is wrong. Think about $A\cap \mathcal P(A)\color{grey}{\ni\{1\}}$.

Comment: 6 is also wrong

Comment: @hhsaffar Yes, thank you. I edited the comment.

Comment: @Mac Can you tell us why you chose each answer? This way we can help you better

Comment: @hhsaffer: 1)I chose ∈ as I did not see {} and thought it could not be a subset.  I am still unclear if {1,2} is the same as {1}∪{2}. For 4) would it be a subset if it was {{{2}}}?

Comment: It is the case that $\{1\} \cup \{2\} = \{1,2\}$, why because the symbol '$\cup$'is union. This means that given any two sets to make a union is to create a new set that contains all the elements in both sets. That means that your answer to 2) was wrong since $\{1,2\}$ is 'an element' of A, not a subset.

Comment: Now if it was $\{\{1,2\}\}$ then it would surely be a subset to A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning number 1. 
$\varnothing$ is the set with no elements. It is not the same as $\left\{ {\varnothing}\right\}$, which is the set with one element i.e $\varnothing \in \left\{ {\varnothing}\right\}$.

Also, do you know the definition of set union? I think once you look at the definition things will become clear.